# When saving a Word 2016 document, how can I automatically save a secondary copy at a specified location?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I use casework management software that I draft letters in, which it can then open up in Word for further editing or printing. The Word document is created in the background and stored remotely, so the document that opens isn't just transferring the letter contents to a new Word document. Any changes in Word can be saved and the updated version is transferred remotely in the background, without me having to specify a save location every time.

What I would like to do is save a local second copy of each Word document created and opened from the casework software (but only the casework software!), but without having to specify a location every time. The location wouldn't change. Is there a way I can tell Word to also save a second copy at a specified location without me having to use Save As?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way I can tell Word to also save a second copy at a specified location?

Yes. You can modify the `FileSave` command:

> This example takes you through the steps needed to modify the FileSave command.
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> .
> 2. In the Macros in box, select Word commands.
> 3. In the Macro name box, select "FileSave".
> 4. In the Macros in box, select a template or document location to store the macro. For example, select "Normal.dot (Global Template)" to
>      create a global macro (this modifies the FileSave command for all
>      documents that use the normal tempate).
> 5. Click Create.
>
> The FileSave macro appears as shown below.
>
> ```
> Sub FileSave() 
> ' 
> ' FileSave Macro 
> ' Saves the active document or template 
> ' 
>     ActiveDocument.Save 
>
> End Sub
> ```
>
> You can add additional instructions or remove the existing
>   `ActiveDocument.Save` instruction. Now every time the `FileSave`
>   command runs, your `FileSave` macro runs instead of the Word command.
>   To restore the original `FileSave` functionality, you need to rename
>   or delete your `FileSave` macro.

Source [Modifying a Word Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/modifying-a-word-command)